# How to log each method's exection time on a page, business and data access layer in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, logging, monitoring, aop, health-monitoring

I have a complex ASP.NET application and it's running since 2009.
I need to monitor it's performance and determine which methods in which layers are time or resource consuming. Then I can optimize methods.

Right now, I'm using SQL Profiler to check the queries and I tune the database step by step. I want to do the same for other layers (UI, Service, and Repository).

I've used [Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) and Enterprise Library Policy Injection Application Block.

I've implemented some attributes and add them to some classes which helps me to get BeforeMethodEntry and AfterMethodEntry (AOP model) automatically. Therefore, I can get the execution time of each method. It also handles exception log and page view log.

But, I think there may be another implemented/standard solution to monitor the running application.

PS: I've implemented some other solution like implementing ExceptionHttpModule and PageViewHttpModule which don't need any Third Party libraries. It doesn't meet my requirements.

**In a simple words, I want to log and monitor layer's activities (specially mehod execution duration). **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into [Spring.Net Aop](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html). If you an *AroundAdvice*, you will be able to start a StopWatch before the execution of the method, and stopping right after it finishes. There is a way to use it as you would with PostSharp (i.e. using attributes).